# How to hide Google Chrome windows with Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to hide Google Chrome windows when i start my program (Java)? It is very annoying when Selenium opens a browser window on top of any other windows I have opened every ~10 seconds. I found some ways for IE and Firefox, but not for Chrome.

Comment: you could use PhantomJS instead of chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna see the Chrome browser, go for a headless option. As suggested in comments, you can use `XVFB` or `PhantomJS`. Starting Chrome 59, you can have a `--headless` flag in chrome too, which you can use via `Chrome Options` in your code, which will make chrome headless and you will not be shown any browser window.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can avoid the annoying the chrome screen. Just select the projector button and select extend screen option. 
Once script launches chrome browser, you can drag it out of the screen where either you can it in your new monitor(if connected) or you dont see any.